# How would one create an endpoint that accepts either a basic auth header or an oauth2 access token?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I've set up an OAuth2 authentication server using spring boot security and everything is working well. What I want to do next is create a super-user that can send requests to every endpoint with just a basic auth header without affecting the authentication flow of other users. Is this possible with spring boot security?

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

One option is using ROLES, so you can select which user access each endpoint with the @Secured annotation.

Other option consist in implement your own filter to run before requests.
This is a simple example using JWT Token filter and validation:

```
public class JWTConfigurer extends SecurityConfigurerAdapter<DefaultSecurityFilterChain, HttpSecurity> {

@Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) {
        JWTFilter customFilter = new JWTFilter();
        http.addFilterBefore(customFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

}
```

```
public class JWTFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
// Here go your implementation
        String jwt = resolveToken(httpServletRequest);
        if (isTokenValid(jwt)) {
            Authentication authentication = getAuthenticationFromToken(jwt);
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
    }

private String resolveToken(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String bearerToken = request.getHeader("YOUR-AUTHORIZATION-HEADER");
        if (StringUtils.hasText(bearerToken) && bearerToken.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            return bearerToken.substring(7, bearerToken.length());
        }
        return null;
    }
```